# Segmentation fault in boost log

Tags: c++, boost-log

I can not reproduce this bug, it seems relates to multi-thread problem. Here is core dump:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000678c98 in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::~attribute_value_set() ()
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f40c3731700 (LWP 24642))]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000678c98 in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::~attribute_value_set() ()
#1  0x000000000067d4ec in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&) ()
#2  0x000000000041c65c in boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Logger::severity_level, ChannelType>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, Logger::severity_level const> > (this=0x7f40b4005148) at /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:259
#3  boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_channel_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Logger::severity_level, ChannelType>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >, ChannelType>::open_record_with_channel_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, Logger::severity_level const> > (args=..., this=0x7f40b4005148) at /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/channel_feature.hpp:195
#4  boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_channel_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Logger::severity_level, ChannelType>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >, ChannelType>::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, Logger::severity_level const> > (args=..., this=0x7f40b4005148) at /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/channel_feature.hpp:171
#5  boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_channel_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Logger::severity_level, ChannelType>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >, ChannelType>, Logger::severity_level>::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, Logger::severity_level const> > (args=..., this=0x7f40b4005148)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp:253
#6  boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Logger::severity_level, ChannelType>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<Logger::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::channel<ChannelType> > >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, Logger::severity_level const> > (this=0x7f40b4005148, args=...)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:459
```

There is my code: Logger.h

```
enum ChannelType {
    main_channel,
    motion_check_channel
};
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(channel, "Channel", ChannelType)

class Logger {
public:
    enum severity_level
    {
        debug,
        info,
        warning,
        error,
        fatal
    };
    static void init(Logger::severity_level level);
    static std::mutex mx;
};
#define LOGD BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS( gl::get(), (set_get_attrib("File", path_to_filename(__FILE__))) (set_get_attrib("Line", __LINE__))\
        (boost::log::keywords::severity = (Logger::debug)) )
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt< Logger::severity_level, ChannelType > logger_type1;
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_CTOR_ARGS(gl, logger_type1, (boost::log::keywords::channel = main_channel))
inline decltype(auto) set_get_attrib(const char* name, const std::string& value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(Logger::mx);
    auto attr = boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()[name]);
    attr.set(value);
    return attr.get();
}

inline decltype(auto) set_get_attrib(const char* name, const int value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(Logger::mx);
    auto attr = boost::log::attribute_cast<boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<int>>(boost::log::core::get()->get_global_attributes()[name]);
    attr.set(value);
    return attr.get();
}


inline std::string path_to_filename(const std::string& path)
{
    return path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
}

int main() {
    Logger::init(Logger::debug);
    LOGD<<"something";
}
```

Logger.cpp

```
void Logger::init(Logger::severity_level level)
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::core> core = boost::log::core::get();
    core->set_exception_handler(boost::log::make_exception_suppressor()); //disable exception. in case file write permission problem

    core->get()->add_global_attribute("Scope", boost::log::attributes::named_scope()); 
    core->get()->add_global_attribute("File", boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>(""));
    core->get()->add_global_attribute("Line", boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<int>(0));
    //core->set_filter(boost::log::expressions::attr<Logger::severity_level>("Severity") >= level);
#ifdef _DEBUG
    {
        typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_ostream_backend> cout_sink;
        boost::shared_ptr<cout_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<cout_sink>();
        boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream> stream(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter());
        sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
        sink->set_filter(channel == main_channel && boost::log::expressions::attr<Logger::severity_level>("Severity") >= level);
        core->add_sink(sink);
    }
    boost::log::add_file_log(
        boost::log::keywords::filter = channel == main_channel && boost::log::expressions::attr<Logger::severity_level>("Severity") >= level,
        //boost::log::keywords::filter = channel == main_channel,
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "./log/%Y%m%d.log",
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
        boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), 
        //boost::log::keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%__LINE__%] (%LineID%) {%ThreadID%}: %Message%"
        boost::log::keywords::format = (
            boost::log::expressions::stream
            << "[" << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f") << "] "
            << "(" << boost::log::expressions::attr<unsigned int>("LineID") << ") "
            << "(" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::aux::thread::id>("ThreadID") << ") "
            << '[' << boost::log::expressions::attr<std::string>("File") << ":"
            << boost::log::expressions::attr<int>("Line") << "] "
            << boost::log::expressions::smessage
            )
        );
}
```

I am use MT version logger, so the multi thread problem should care by log lib itself, but this crash happen random (my app is multi threaded)

Comment: Would you mind to remove the horizontal scrollbars?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, if possible.

Comment: I only paste the boost log related stack, others are my code which just call LOGD<<"message";

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is the cause of the crash, but my first suspects are your `set_get_attrib` functions, which are probably incorrect and not doing what you intended. First, `core::get_global_attributes()` returns a **copy** of the attribute set, so you can't add/remove attributes used by the core. Next, both the subscript operator and `attribute_cast` may return an empty attribute indicating that there is no such attribute or that it has a different type. You call `set` on it without checking. Next, the value returned from `set_get_attrib` is unused by the logger and is discarded.

Comment: I use them to add file name and line number in the log and it indeed works. Frankly I don't really know how it work, some parts of this lib are too complex for me. So I am searching and keep trying, find out it works. Maybe you could show the correct usage to add file name and line number?

Comment: Did you try `add_value` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.manipulators.add_value) manipulator?

Comment: It doesn't work. I change my LOGD to "#define LOGD BOOST_LOG_SEV(gl::get(), Logger::debug)<<boost::log::add_value("File", path_to_filename(__FILE__))<<boost::log::add_value("Line", __LINE__)" and add “”LOGD<<"aaa";" in main, it prints "[2017-05-11_20:25:38.856778] (1) (0x00002824) [:0] aaa" which it should be "[2017-05-11_20:25:38.859778] (2) (0x00002824) [main.cpp:37] aaa"

Comment: Use add_value, after I comment out "core->get()->add_global_attribute("File", boost::log::attributes::mutable_constant<std::string>(""));" in init(), the file name can be printed, but line number still missing

Comment: You also need to remove `add_global_attribute` calls for `File` and `Line` in `Logger::init()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143877/discussion-between-jean-and-andrey-semashev).